# How to fix b2Assert(kNormal > b2_epsilon) error in b2ContactlSolver?

Tags: box2d, assert, box2d-iphone

In my iPhone app game the main character traps enemies (represented by b2bodies) in small spaces.  Sometimes when too many enemies are trapped in too small of a space my game fails the b2Assert(kNormal > b2_epsilon).

What danger is there in ignoring this assert?  In my game once the enemies are trapped in a small space there's not much use left for them, so if they behave in a non-physical way that's fine.  However if ignoring this assert causes other problems with the box2D physics engine outside the scope of the trapped b2body, then I need to try and fix it.  If so, how would I fix it?

Lastly, are Asserts fired in the release build of an app?

Answer (score 0):

This assert [was removed](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/detail?r=186&path=/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/Contacts/b2ContactSolver.cpp) from b2ContactSolver.cpp in Jun 18, 2011. Try to update your Box2D.

Asserts is only tool for debug, they are not fired and never executes in the release build.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can happen if you ignore an assert. They won't be triggered in release builds. Still, you **have** to treat them as fatal program errors.

An assertion is used to make sure the input of a method is within defined boundaries, or the conditions for running the method are valid. If this is not the case, and the program asserts, then the result of the method is undefined. It might simply be ignored and deliver no results (though this can trickle down into other parts of the code, causing follow-up bugs there). Or it will simply crash, immediately or even just randomly at a later time.

You need to figure out the exact circumstances of this assert, then ensure that these circumstances do not happen. If enemies can be trapped in small spaces, make sure that doesn't happen - how you do that is up to you.